# How to average values from columns that shared the same substring in column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'probe':["a","b","c","d"], 'gene':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 'cellA.1':[5,0,1,0], 'cellA.2':[12,90,13,0],'cellB.1':[15,3,11,2],'cellB.2':[5,7,11,1]  })
df = df[["probe", "gene","cellA.1","cellA.2","cellB.1","cellB.2"]]
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
  probe gene  cellA.1  cellA.2  cellB.1  cellB.2
0     a  foo        5       12       15        5
1     b  bar        0       90        3        7
2     c  qux        1       13       11       11
3     d  woz        0        0        2        1
```

Note that the values are contained in column that shared  same substring (e.g. cellA and cellB). In real case the cell ID can be more than these two and numerical index can also be more (e.g. CellFoo.5)

What I want to do is to get the average so that it looks like this

```
     probe gene  cellA  cellB
     a  foo        9.5     10      
     b  bar        45      5       
     c  qux        7       11       
     d  woz        0       1.5
```

How can I achieve that with Pandas?

Comment: Are the first two columns always the same (name)?

Comment: Phrased another way; are the columns of interest always the third+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to make a function which takes a column name and turns it into the group you want to put it in:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(["probe", "gene"])
>>> df.groupby(lambda x: x.split(".")[0], axis=1).mean()
            cellA  cellB
probe gene              
a     foo     8.5   10.0
b     bar    45.0    5.0
c     qux     7.0   11.0
d     woz     0.0    1.5
>>> df.groupby(lambda x: x.split(".")[0], axis=1).mean().reset_index()
  probe gene  cellA  cellB
0     a  foo    8.5   10.0
1     b  bar   45.0    5.0
2     c  qux    7.0   11.0
3     d  woz    0.0    1.5
```

Note that we set the index (and reset it afterwards) so we didn't have to special-case the groups we didn't want to touch; also note we had to specify `axis=1` because we want to group columnwise, not rowwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'probe':["a","b","c","d"], 'gene':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 'cellA.1':[5,0,1,0], 'cellA.2':[12,90,13,0],'cellB.1':[15,3,11,2],'cellB.2':[5,7,11,1]  })
df = df[["probe", "gene","cellA.1","cellA.2","cellB.1","cellB.2"]]

mask = df.columns.str.contains(".", regex=False)
df1 = df.loc[:, ~mask]
df2 = df.loc[:, mask]
pd.concat([df1, df2.groupby(lambda name:name.split(".")[0], axis=1).mean()], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension.

```
In [1]: df['cellA'] = [(x+y)/2. for x,y in zip(df['cellA.1'], df['cellA.2'])]
In [2]: df['cellB'] = [(x+y)/2. for x,y in zip(df['cellB.1'], df['cellB.2'])]
In [3]: df = df[['probe', 'gene', 'cellA', 'cellB']]
In [4]: df
Out [4]: 
     probe gene  cellA  cellB
     a     foo   8.5    10.0      
     b     bar   45.0   5.0       
     c     qux   7.0    11.0       
     d     woz   0.0    1.5
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not general enough. I have to hardcode 
`df['cellA.1'], df['cellA.2']`, where in reality it can be less or more than 2.